# Type Error: Map Is Not a Function: Twitter API with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twitter

i'm working to try and display some twitter data in a React component.

I'm successfully grabbing the data via my server (express) but getting this 'map is not a function error' when trying to display some sample data.  After digging around for a while, it appears that this is likely because when the component is mounted, that the 'tweets' variable is undefined--(I THINK?)  --but i'm not really sure how to solve it.  Would appreciate any advice.  Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tweets:[];
    }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/tweets')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({tweets: res.statuses})
        })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.tweets) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>Users</h1>
           {this.state.tweets.map(tweet =>
              <div key={tweet.id}>{tweet.text}</div>
              )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here's my backend in case you need it:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Twit = require('twit');
const config = require('./config');

var T = new Twit(config);

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      T.get('search/tweets', { q: "$GOOG" })
          .then(function(result) {
            var tweets = result.statuses;
            res.send({"statuses": tweets});
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('caught error', err.stack)
            res.send({ error: err })
          })
      })

module.exports = router;
```

And here's what the format of my output looks like--directly from the server json output:

```
{
tweets: {
statuses: [
{
created_at: "Wed Jan 24 23:50:01 +0000 2018",
id: 956313169663791100,
id_str: "956313169663791104",
text: "RT @techeblog: #Google Pixel 3 XL spotted in video based on leaks, could be #iPhoneX Plus competitor.  #pixel2 #pixe…",
truncated: false,
entities: {
hashtags: [
{
text: "Google",
indices: [
15,
22
]
},
{
text: "iPhoneX",
indices: [
76,
84
]
},
{
text: "pixel2",
indices: [
126,
133
]
}
],
symbols: [ ],
user_mentions: [
{
screen_name: "techeblog",
name: "TechEBlog",
id: 19600067,
id_str: "19600067",
indices: [
3,
13
]
}
],
```

Comment: can you confirm that `res.statuses` is an `Array`?

Comment: On the server, you're grabbing `result.statuses` and sending that as the key `tweets`. On the client, you're again accessing `res.statuses`, but I think you should be accessing `res.tweets`.

Comment: I just posted a sample of the JSON output.  Twitter data is organized at the top level by 'statuses'.  So each tweet is organized within these statuses.

Comment: This is wrong: `res.send({tweets});`.  Probably you want to send is: `res.send({"statuses": tweets});`

Comment: okay okay i see what you guys are saying.  made changes and now no errors---but just get the "Loading" text with no data

Comment: if you send `tweets`, an Object, then it wont be an Array - it seems that `res` will be `tweets:[array of statuses]` - so, it's confusing as is, but `this.setState({tweets: res.tweets})` would work - but I'd be inclined to name things properly, otherwise your future self will hate you :p

Comment: I updated above code--so just to be clear in the backend i did change to send res.send({"statuses": tweets});   and now just getting the 'loading' text

Comment: also in console, the state in React is empty

Comment: oh wow--i just figured it out---in componentDidMount i needed to set state like this with the statuses label `this.setState({tweets: data.tweets.statuses})`

Comment: thanks for all your help